# How do i extract the words between two character?

Tags: r

```
<td>hello world</td>xxxx
```

I would like to extract this hello world but I tried to extract but somehow it either stops at hello or its everything after hello including the next <, How do I extract the word hello world without taking in other character(meaning to stop taking at <)

Comment: I'd suggest checking out packages such as [XML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) which are made for exactly these things.

Comment: `xml2::xml_text()`?

Comment: `sub(".*<td>(.*)</td>.*", "\\1", "<td>hello world</td>xxxx")`